# Echo Last Auto-increment ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want the below code to display the last Auto-increment id on a php page. Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php 
    include '../db_connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT max(id) FROM  receipt";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: What does it return that makes you believe it is wrong?

Comment: $last_id = $conn->insert_id;

Comment: It displays nothing

Comment: `$conn->lastInsertId();`

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching the mysql result:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

If you need only one row:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array()
print $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you this you can get next auto increment id of table:

`SELECT Auto_increment AS id FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table name' AND table_schema = 'databse_name'`

Comment: Displaying this in a PHP page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will solve your issue

```
<?php 
      include '../db_connection.php';
      $sql = "SELECT max(id) FROM  receipt";
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
            echo $result;
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use $conn->lastInsertId(); function which returned the last inserted id in a table.